# Home page don't load at first visit, when the slider image is active - Prestashop

Tags: javascript, themes, prestashop-1.7

I have bought a prestashop theme, and as the website is getting ready, i have face a problem that is related to the image slider module, that came with the theme.

When the module is active the home page don't load at the first time/visit, only when i refresh it, that happens in every browser except on mozila firefox. The prestashop version is 1.7.6.7.7.

I already set degug mode and don't show any error, i have already disable all modules and when the iamge slider is disable the website works. I also have comment this code on custom.js because of this error: $(...).fancybox is not a function

```
  /*=============fancybox============*/
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });
});
```

But the problem persists... The website link is: https://acenor.pcsolution.pt/

Can anyone give a help? Any more ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the website does not load at all rather than it takes a very long time to load? When the site does not load, can you see any error in console? What is the average file size of the images you use in the slider and how many images does it display?

Comment: Also, looking at the console, you have an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and looking at your page source it seems you load all the JavaScript at the bottom of the `<body></body>`; try moving the external libraries in the `<head></head>` and make sure the rest of the code is loaded in the correct order (e.g. if fileA.js relies on some code inside fileB.js, make sure you loaf fileB.js before fileA.js)

Comment: Hi, yes the website don't load at all... The images are optimized, i also tried with only one image and the behavior is the same. In the console when the website don't load theres this error: 

itimageslider.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).nivoSlider is not a function
    at itimageslider.js:27
    at dispatch (core.js:39)
    at g.handle (core.js:39)

The "itimageslider" is the module of the slider. When we refresh and the site loads the error don't show.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your elements IDs and class attributes. (1) In "itimageslider.js" you are trying to access an element with the id 'slider' (see `jQuery("#slider").nivoSlider(...)`) but you do not have any in your page. (2) In "product.bundle.js" you are trying to access elements with the class 'thumbnail-container' (see `e.querySelector(".thumbnail-container").append(t)`) but you do not have any in your page (you seem to have `innovatory-thumbnail-container` instead) [...]

Comment: [...] Apart from that, you seem to have another couple of errors linked to `owlCarousel` not being a function and to `$` not being defined

Comment: Finally, looking at the network tab of the DevTool, it seems jQuery is taking more time than all others javascript files to load, therefore all scripts depending on jQuery that try to execute before jQuery is loaded fails. After a couple of refresh, jQuery has finally loaded and is served from the cache, therefore you do not experience the same problem (unless you clear the cache or the caching time expires)

Comment: Anyway, even when it loads, your website takes way too much time to display anything and could use some optimization. If you are not a professional developer yourself, I'd recommend seeking the support of a local developer; after all, if your e-commerce does not work it does not sell and if does not sell it is just cost without any ROI so the money you spend today to hire a developer are likely to save you a much larger sum in the long run. (Just to be clear, I am **not** pitching for the job).